# SVG logo text instead of an image used in froont.com?

Tags: svg, html

I am looking at the design of a website http://www.froont.com and they seem to generate the logo text using SVG. I am totally unable to understand how to generate logo text this way? Help is appreciated in understanding whats going on here?

Here is the what I see in the HTML source.

image/svg+xml

```
<g transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,405.36856,595.03461)" id="g3099">
  <path d="m 0,0 -11.312,0 0,5.734 29.193,0 0,-5.734 -11.313,0 0,-31.174 -6.568,0 L 0,0 z" id="path3101" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,172.28019,587.86661)" id="g3079">
  <path d="m 0,0 23.823,0 0,-5.734 -17.255,0 0,-10.113 16.266,0 0,-5.526 -16.266,0 0,-15.535 -6.568,0 L 0,0 z" id="path3081" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,223.90856,607.74086)" id="g3083">
  <path d="m 0,0 c 3.703,0 7.925,0.886 7.925,5.37 0,4.014 -3.962,5.004 -7.351,5.004 l -5.942,0 L -5.368,0 0,0 z m -11.937,15.899 12.824,0 c 6.933,0 13.605,-2.762 13.605,-10.582 0,-5.317 -3.283,-8.809 -8.444,-9.957 l 9.852,-16.369 -7.923,0 -8.549,15.64 -4.796,0 0,-15.64 -6.569,0 0,36.908 z" id="path3085" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,317.20206,627.81049)" id="g3091">
  <path d="m 0,0 c 7.559,0 12.72,5.734 12.72,13.605 0,7.612 -5.056,13.502 -12.72,13.502 -7.612,0 -12.668,-5.89 -12.668,-13.502 C -12.668,5.734 -7.508,0 0,0 m -0.053,32.894 c 11.522,0 19.913,-7.455 19.913,-19.289 0,-11.519 -8.391,-19.496 -19.913,-19.496 -11.364,0 -19.756,7.977 -19.756,19.496 0,11.834 8.392,19.289 19.756,19.289" id="path3093" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,269.63856,627.81049)" id="g3087">
  <path d="m 0,0 c 7.558,0 12.719,5.734 12.719,13.605 0,7.612 -5.057,13.502 -12.719,13.502 -7.611,0 -12.668,-5.89 -12.668,-13.502 C -12.668,5.734 -7.508,0 0,0 m -0.053,32.894 c 11.521,0 19.913,-7.455 19.913,-19.289 0,-11.519 -8.392,-19.496 -19.913,-19.496 -11.364,0 -19.757,7.977 -19.757,19.496 0,11.834 8.393,19.289 19.757,19.289" id="path3089" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,346.27181,587.86661)" id="g3095">
  <path d="m 0,0 8.705,0 17.15,-27.628 0.105,0 0,27.628 6.568,0 0,-36.908 -8.341,0 -17.514,28.515 -0.106,0 0,-28.515 -6.567,0 L 0,0 z" id="path3097" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's normal that you don't see texts, that's just because there is no text. The logo is the paths you are copyng. You see, 6 paths, each one for each letter. If you have a vector drawing program it's really common to write a text and have the option to 'create the outlines'. Then the text is lost and what you get is the paths of each letter.

The important question is if this is a good SEO option. If you check the code, you can see the h1 of the page don't have the name of the company, and that's a common pattern.